# html2pdf: a table with more than 40000 rows

Tags: php, html, css, pdf, html2pdf

I tried to use html2pdf.fr to create a pdf for a table with about 40'000 rows. Unfortunately it takes to much time. for about 1'000 Records I just have to wait about one minute and the CPU-load of the server is about 99%. Does anyone has an idea to perform the creation?
The table is quite simple without any css.

Thanks

Comment: you can change the max_execution_time of php (phi.ini)  to 2 minute progrmaticlly using `ini_set('max_execution_time','120')`. Or best one that first 100 records and then so-on.

Comment: the time_limit is already set to 0, otherwise it doesn't work. thanks for your proposal with 100 records, but i guess that's not working in html2pdf